# Mailkit and search in html Mail on IMAP

Tags: mailkit

I search with powershell in my IMAP directory for mails that have a certain text module.
Unfortunately, this only works with text / plain mails.

However, if the mail consists of HTML (text / html), nothing is found.
Are there options for SearchQuery that text can also be found in HTML mails?

My search string:

`$suchen1 = [MailKit.Search.SearchQuery]::FromContains ($mail_From).And([MailKit.Search.SearchQuery]::SubjectContains($mail_Subject)).And([MailKit.Search.SearchQuery]::DeliveredOn($today)).And([MailKit.Search.SearchQuery]::MessageContains($mail_Message))`

Answer (score 0):

MailKit doesn’t do client-side searches for IMAP. Instead, it sends your search query to the server and just gives you the match results that the IMAP server returns.

There is also no HTML-aware IMAP search query mechanism, so you are out of luck.